# Can I use a filter inside a filter in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, angularjs-scope

I just create a filter to convert my date to time. And I would call in the official filter "date" of AngularJS.

`project.date_created_at` and `project.mel` don't have the same format. So I need to create a custom filter for `project.date_created_at`.

**HTML :**

```
<span>{{ project.date_created_at | dateCustom }}</span>
<span>{{ project.mel | date:'dd/MM/yyyy' }}</span>
```

**JS :**

```
myApp.filter('dateCustom', function () {
    return function (input) {

        if(input != undefined) {
            var d = new Date(input);
            var time = d.getTime();
            // use official $filter('date') here ?
        }

    }
});
```

I would like to use this format :

```
date:'dd/MM/yyyy'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can inject $filter as a dependency like you would do it for a controller, a service or a directive.

```
myApp.filter('myFilter',[ '$filter', function ($filter) {
    return function (input) {
      /**
         Do your stuff
      **/
      return $filter('date')(myDate,myFormat);
    }
}]);
```

On a side note, you should use [angular.isDefined](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.isDefined) instead of `!= undefined`.

See the documentation of [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24filter) and of [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for more details